# Function to export last available value of list of stocks to .csv

Tags: r, function, quantmod

I'm trying to export to a .csv some  data coming from Quantmod.

What I'd like to export into a .csv is the name of the Ticker and the last data available in my list regarding the volume (Vol)

Let me explain my approach:

## Load a list of tickers from a .csv into my environment

```
library(quantmod)
Tickers <- read.csv("nasdaq_tickers_list.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

getSymbols(Tickers$Tickers,from="2018-08-01", src="yahoo" )
stock_data = sapply(.GlobalEnv, is.xts)
all_stocks <- do.call(list, mget(names(stock_data)[stock_data]))
```

## Let's have a look into for example the "Tail" of MSFT

```
            MSFT.Open   MSFT.High MSFT.Low MSFT.Close MSFT.Volume MSFT.Adjusted
2018-09-28    114.19    114.57   113.68     114.37    21647800        114.37
2018-10-01    114.75    115.68   114.73     115.61    18883100        115.61
2018-10-02    115.30    115.84   114.44     115.15    20787200        115.15
2018-10-03    115.42    116.18   114.93     115.17    16648000        115.17
2018-10-04    114.61    114.76   111.63     112.79    34821700        112.79
2018-10-05    112.63    113.17   110.64     112.13    29064300        112.13
```

## If we use "last" we get the latest volume available data in my list

```
last(MSFT$MSFT.Volume)

             MSFT.Volume
2018-10-05    29064300
```

## Now, I'd like to create a function to get the last available "Volume" data of all tickers in my list (all_stocks) exported into a .csv file.

The desired output is a .csv file with the Ticker name and the last Volume data.

```
MSFT,29064300
stock1,volume1
stock2,volume2
```

Any help on how to approach?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a function to get the last volume per stock. Then you can use lapply to get the data, but I wrapped it in `Reduce` with rbind to get everything nicely in a data.frame ready for writing to a csv.

```
stock_last_volume <- function(x) {
  stock_name <- stringi::stri_extract(names(x)[1], regex = "^[A-Z]+")
  volume <- last(quantmod::Vo(x))
  colnames(volume) <- "volume"
  my_df <- data.frame(stock = stock_name, volume = volume, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = NULL)
  return(my_df)
}


all_volumes <- Reduce(rbind, lapply(all_stocks, stock_last_volume))

all_volumes[1:2, ]
  stock   volume
1  MSFT 29064300
2  GOOG  1184300

# write.csv to working directory
write.csv(all_volumes, file = "all_volumes.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the setup given in the Note at the end, `sapply` over the ticker names extracting the volumes into a named vector `vols`.  Then rework that into a data frame `DF`.  If `file` is specified write it out.  Finally return the data frame.

We show a few different ways of using this.

```
# create data frame of last volumes and optionally log to .csv
lastVols <- function(Names, file, envir = .GlobalEnv) {
  vols <- sapply(Names, function(nm) Vo(last(get(nm, envir))))
  DF <- data.frame(stock = names(vols), volume = unname(vols), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  if (!missing(file)) write.csv(DF, file, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
  DF
}
```

giving:

```
# return volumes and display on stdout()
volsDF <- lastVols(Tickers, stdout())
## stock,volume
## MSFT,29064300
## TSLA,17913000

# returns volumes and log to csv file
volsDF <- lastVols(Tickers, "myfile.csv")

# return volumes; don't log
lastVols(Tickers)
##   stock   volume
## 1  MSFT 29064300
## 2  TSLA 17913000
```

### Note

```
library(quantmod)

Tickers <- c("MSFT", "TSLA")
getSymbols(Tickers)
```

Comment: Thank you very for your approach. Worked fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

The quantmod add-on package `qmao` (https://github.com/gsee/qmao) has a function `PF` ( or `makePriceFrame`, which is the longer name of the same function ) which will get you the volume for the last day or for whatever a day you are interested in, in one line ( the argument `prefer` let you select the column you are interested in ):

```
library(qmao)
getSymbols(c('AAPL','AMZN','MSFT’))

tail(PF(c('AAPL','AMZN','MSFT'),prefer = 'Volume',silent = TRUE),1)
               AAPL    AMZN     MSFT
2018-10-08 28793100 7358200 29633400
```

Comment: I'll have a look. Thanks a lot.